# The storage file is not properly formatted (Unexpected end of JSON) discord.js

Tags: discord, bots, discord.js

I'm working on a giveaway bot and got that error. This is the full error

```
(node:4) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: SyntaxError: The storage file is not properly formatted (Unexpected end of JSON input).
at GiveawaysManager.getAllGiveaways (/app/node_modules/discord-giveaways/src/Manager.js:308:27)
at async GiveawaysManager._init (/app/node_modules/discord-giveaways/src/Manager.js:391:30)
```

Here is my code:

```
const { GiveawaysManager } = require("discord-giveaways");
const manager = new GiveawaysManager(bot, {
    storage: "./giveaways.json",
    updateCountdownEvery: 10000,
    default: {
        botsCanWin: false,
        embedColor: "#FF0000",
        reaction: ""
    }
})

bot.giveawaysManager = manager;
    }
})
```

I'm new to coding so it wil be great if you explain in baby steps

Comment: You haven't provided enough code, nobody knows what the constructor of GiveawaysManager looks like and what it does. Judging from the error message you assume that whatever gets returned from the server side is json data whilst it isn't necessarily so, either that or the server replies with wrongly formatted json.

Answer (score 2):

I had this same issue, and it turns out that the giveaways.json file only had a `[]` in it.
**It is best if you just don't add a file because the module should add one for you!**

Answer (score 0):

The storage file is your `./giveaways.json`. As seen in the [npm documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/discord-giveaways), it saves the file in JSON format which is highly likely to go wrong, make sure that you haven't touched the `giveaways.json` file, much less change it. Adding even a single line in the `giveaways.json` file may cause the `GiveawaysManager` to append wrongly and not be able to read it.

My suggestion is basically **delete the `./giveaways.json` file**. This should refresh the file and be rid of all syntax errors unless it was from the npm module itself. Note that deleting it, will delete and therefore, stop all the giveaways in process, so make sure you have no giveaways in progress.

If this doesn't fix the issue, then **delete the `./giveaways.json` file** again, and **create a new `./giveaways.json` file** with this as it's contents:

```
{}
```